# Javascript: Search array to see if it contains part of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, compare, partial

Using javascript (or Jquery) how would I compare a string of text to an array and return matching values?

For example if I have an array:

```
    var names = ["John", "Mary", "George"];
```

And I have a string:

```
   var sentence = "Did Mary go to the store today?";
```

I want to compare the string and the array and return the matching word, in this example "Mary".

I have searched and everything I have found seems to be comparing for a specific string. What I am looking for is matching PARTIALS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid **Johnathon** matching **John**, you'll want to build a regular expression:

```
var names = ["John", "Mary", "George"];
var regex = new RegExp("(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])(" + names.join("|") + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)", "g");

regex.test("Did Johnathon go to the store today?"); // false
regex.test("Did John go to the store today?");      // true
```

You want to match the name if the name is at the beginning of the string or a non alpha numeric character precedes it `(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])`, AND if the name is at the end of the string or a non alpha numeric character succeeds it `([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)`. Hence the two captures before and after the list of names.

To collect the names:

```
var matches = [];
var sentence = "Did John or Mary go to the store today?";

sentence.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
     matches.push($2);
});

console.log(matches);
```

And a quick reusable function:

```
function getMatchingWords(words, s) {
    var matches = [],
        regex = new RegExp("(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])(" + words.join("|") + ")([^a-zA-Z0-9]|$)", "g");

    s.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2, $3) {
        matches.push($2);
    });

    return matches;
}

var matches = getMatchingWords(["John", "Mary", "Billy"], "Did John or Mary go to the store today?");
```

Comment: Works great, and thanks so much for even adding in a function! How would the regex change if you actually did want Johnathan to match John?

Comment: Just remove the text between the first and last parentheses. It's debatable whether or not the regex or calling `indexOf` inside a loop would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var matches = [];

for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++){
    if(sentence.indexOf(names[i]) != -1){
        matches.push(names[i]);
    }
}

console.log(matches)
```

Comment: That's close, however what if someone was named Johnathon? I suppose there's an argument that `Johnathon == John` because one is short for the other. It depends on how exact you want the match to be.

Comment: true, you could change it to `sentence.indexOf(' '+names[i]+' ')`, but it would fail with punctuations

Answer (score -1):

```js
var sentence = "Did Mary go to the store today?";
var names = ["John", "Mary", "George"];
var found = [];

names.forEach(function(e) {
  if (sentence.toLowerCase().search(e.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    found.push(e);
  }
});

alert(found);
```

Comment: Still, partial name matches are returned (Johnathon matching John) -- although that _could_ be the intended behavior the OP is looking for.

Comment: OP did say: "What I am looking for is matching PARTIALS."